# Get only one row as result set when only one column has different values

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to get only one row as a result when there are several columns with the same value and only one with different values **or, if possible,** getting a row and the column with all those different values in a CSV format

This is how the query looks like
[image]

And this is the SQL part

```
select t.Task_ID,t.task_creator_ID,ttig.Task_taker_Task_taker_ID
from 
Task as t left join assigned_to as tig on t.Task_ID= tig.Task_ID 
        left join taker_in_Group as ttig on tig.Group_ID=ttig.Group_ID 
        left join Task_taker as tt on tt.Task_taker_ID = ttig.Task_taker_Task_taker_ID
        left join task_in_typ as titp on titp.task_ID = t.Task_ID
        left join Typ as tp on titp.typ_ID = tp.typ_ID
        where t.task_creator_ID = 'seam4339';
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `group_concat()`:

```
select t.Task_ID, t.task_creator_ID,
       group_concat(ttig.Task_taker_Task_taker_ID)
from Task t left join
     assigned_to as tig
     on t.Task_ID= tig.Task_ID left join
     taker_in_Group ttig 
     on tig.Group_ID = ttig.Group_ID left join
     Task_taker tt
     on tt.Task_taker_ID = ttig.Task_taker_Task_taker_ID left join
     task_in_typ titp
     on titp.task_ID = t.Task_ID left join
     Typ tp 
     on  titp.typ_ID = tp.typ_ID
where t.task_creator_ID = 'seam4339'
group by t.Task_ID, t.task_creator_ID;
```